# GA4 see metrics from deleted data-stream

Tags: google-analytics

I have deleted a data stream from my GA4 property, but I can still see it's metrics on my reports.

According to [this site](https://www.lovesdata.com/blog/delete-data-stream):

> All of the data collected by the stream will also be erased, and you
> will not be able to recover the data (or the data stream).

How much does time it takes to delete all old-stream metrics from my reports? (I have waited 20 hours)